# Use only parts of an xml-file

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine, serialization

I'm relatively new to Unity and C#. Actually, I mainly look at application code and try to learn a little bit. And that's fun.

Now I've stumbled upon a problem.

I'm trying to read an XML file and continue using the data from it. That even works. But now I don't want to use all records of the XML file, but only those that have a certain ID.

Currently I do it like this:

```
public class Data
{
    public frage[] fragen = new frage[0];

    public Data () { }

    public static void Write(Data data)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Data));
        using (Stream stream = new FileStream (GameUtility.XmlFilePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(stream, data);
        }
    }
    public static Data Fetch ()
    {
        return Fetch(out bool result);
    }
    public static Data Fetch(out bool result)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(GameUtility.XmlFilePath)) { result = false; return new Data(); }

        XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Data));
        using (Stream stream = new FileStream(GameUtility.XmlFilePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            var data = (Data)deserializer.Deserialize(stream);
            result = true;

            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

This causes, I think, that all data is stored in the corresponding variable (data). But now I want only those data sets to be transferred that have the ID 5. Is this possible with simple adjustments or do I have to think about everything?

My data set, which is created via XML, looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Data xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <fragen>
    <frage>
      <info>IRGENDEINTEXT1</info>
      <antworten>
        <antwort>
          <info>1</info>
          <korrekt>true</korrekt>
        </antwort>
        <antwort>
          <info>2</info>
          <korrekt>false</korrekt>
        </antwort>
        <antwort>
          <info>3</info>
          <korrekt>false</korrekt>
        </antwort>
        <antwort>
          <info>4</info>
          <korrekt>false</korrekt>
        </antwort>
      </antworten>
      <id>5</id>
    </frage>
    <frage>
      <info>IRGENDEINTEXT2</info>
      <antworten>
        <antwort>
          <info>1</info>
          <korrekt>false</korrekt>
        </antwort>
        <antwort>
          <info>2</info>
          <korrekt>false</korrekt>
        </antwort>
        <antwort>
          <info>3</info>
          <korrekt>false</korrekt>
        </antwort>
        <antwort>
          <info>4</info>
          <korrekt>true</korrekt>
        </antwort>
      </antworten>
      <id>7</id>
    </frage>
  </fragen>
</Data>
```

Thank you - I hope my question is meaningful and not too unclear. Forgive my incorrect English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have, but I would advise against reading only partial files all the time because that is a constant IO hit. Every time you would need to fetch a new question you get another read IO on the disk. Unless your set of questions is humongous (e.g. several hundred MB), you could read all data into your `Data` object at game start and then just add a helper function into your `Data` class that supplies you with the relevant information. E.g.

```cs
class Data {
   private Frage[] fragen;   

   // Read a Frage by ID
   public Frage QuestionById(string id) {
       return this.fragen.First(it => it.id == id);
   }

}
```

Same for the answers:

```cs
class Frage {
    private Antwort[] antworten;
    public Antwort GetCorrectAnswer() {
       return antworten.First(it => it.korrekt);
    }
}
```

Then in your game logic you can just call:

```cs
var aFrage = data.QuestionById("4711");
var anAntwort = aFrage.GetCorrectAnswer();
```

You could theoretically also use XPath to just select the XML nodes you need, but for this to work you would still need to load the whole XML document into memory in order to run your XPath over it (I'm unaware of any XPath implementation for .net that would work on streams). So you may as well just use your own data structure as I have laid out.

If you really need a huge data set and cannot load everything into memory, you should maybe look at some database solution, e.g. SQLite to store your data. This would allow you to do SQL DB queries and doesn't require you to load all the data into memory.

Comment: That was an incredible help. I was able to solve my problem with a few adjustments as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jan Thomä. What you do is called deserialization (when you create an xml or json from an object you do a serialization). So you just create an object from your xml file (of course tecnically you need to read the file to deserialize it but, of course, you use a library to handle it). Once you got the data you should be able to change your object or create a modified copy with your correct data.

Usually I prefer json so I'm not sure how to do it with XmlSerializer library (link with an example in the edit part) but you should create a bean object that is a representation of your xml file
(example antwort is one of the basic object and it should have a int info variable and a korrekt boolean variable, while antworten is an object that only contains a List of antwort and so on until you reach your main object fragen that contains all your basic rappresentation of your xml bean to deserialize (to create a bean just declare your variables and Getter/Setters for those variables))

After that you just deserialize your xml as a Fragen instead of as a Data type and you can than change your object the easy way.

EDIT. To undestand it better just look the example here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize?view=netframework-4.8

you got the xml and the class that representate the object OrderedItem (note: the namespace should be optional but you need to call the variable with the same name of the variable in your xml and you should need getter and setter in OrderedItem class). Once you got OrderedItem item it's easy to read/write new value to the object, serialize a new xml with new data or just create a modified copy of your object.
You should just do the same thing.

Example from the link:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

// This is the class that will be deserialized.
public class OrderedItem
{
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://www.cpandl.com")]
    public string ItemName;
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://www.cpandl.com")]
    public string Description;
    [XmlElement(Namespace="http://www.cohowinery.com")]
    public decimal UnitPrice;
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://www.cpandl.com")]
    public int Quantity;
    [XmlElement(Namespace="http://www.cohowinery.com")]
    public decimal LineTotal;
    // A custom method used to calculate price per item.
    public void Calculate()
    {
        LineTotal = UnitPrice * Quantity;
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Test t = new Test();
        // Read a purchase order.
        t.DeserializeObject("simple.xml");
    }

    private void DeserializeObject(string filename)
    {   
        Console.WriteLine("Reading with Stream");
        // Create an instance of the XmlSerializer.
        XmlSerializer serializer = 
        new XmlSerializer(typeof(OrderedItem));

        // Declare an object variable of the type to be deserialized.
        OrderedItem i;

        using (Stream reader = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
        {
            // Call the Deserialize method to restore the object's state.
            i = (OrderedItem)serializer.Deserialize(reader);          
        }

        // Write out the properties of the object.
        Console.Write(
        i.ItemName + "\t" +
        i.Description + "\t" +
        i.UnitPrice + "\t" +
        i.Quantity + "\t" +
        i.LineTotal);
    }
}
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <OrderedItem xmlns:inventory="http://www.cpandl.com" xmlns:money="http://www.cohowinery.com">
   <inventory:ItemName>Widget</inventory:ItemName>
   <inventory:Description>Regular Widget</inventory:Description>
   <money:UnitPrice>2.3</money:UnitPrice>
   <inventory:Quantity>10</inventory:Quantity>
   <money:LineTotal>23</money:LineTotal>
 </OrderedItem>
```